# How can I disable cooling with a White Rodgers thermostat?

Tags: thermostat

[1F56W-444 White Rodgers Thermostat](http://www.emersonclimate.com/Documents/White-Rodgers/instruction_sheets/0037-5026.pdf)

I am fairly sure this is the thermostat that I have. How do I disconnect the cooler/air-conditioner as to avoid my penguin visiting relative waking me to 55°F chills.

Comment: Would your relative notice if you turned the main switch of the AC unit to 'off'? Or sneakier would be to trip the breaker at the panel...

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect the wire connected to the `Y` terminal. This is the terminal that's energized when the thermostat calls for cool, so disconnecting the wire will prevent the thermostat from calling for cool.